# How to Find a String in a Directory of Files Using grep and glob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, rake

So I've been messing with this for the last hour and a half or so and just can not figure out how to do this.

In my Ruby test.rake file, which gets called from another project after a Snapshot Gem is created, I need to check to see if a dependency for Capybara exists in the Rakefile for the other project, since we have since deprecated Capybara and are replacing it with something else.

So, I included a simple check to see if the project contains Feature/Capybara tests, and if so, to scan through each spec test and see if it has dependency for Capybara in it, and if so log a warning to tell the user that Capybara has been deprecated.

My problem is, I can not get this to work at all. When I attach this to a Jenkins job and run it, I keep getting the unexpected Print statement in the else clause.

Am I missing something here? From what I understand, my code is doing the following things:

1. Checking if the spec/features directory exists
2. Using glob to select all of the files in the directory that end with .rb (Spec tests), with each file instance being assigned to **file**
3. Take the current instance of **file**, read each line of it, and use grep to find any instances of the word "capybara" in them, and print out the right message if found.
4. Else, if the word is NOT found, print the error message in the else clause.

I'm somewhat new to Ruby so I feel like maybe I am missing something with the syntax, but other than that I'm stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is what the code and the Rakefile I am trying to parse through look like:

**test.rake:**

```
  if Dir.exist?('spec/features')
      path = 'spec/features/'
      Dir.glob(path + '*.rb') {|file|
        if File.readlines(file).grep(/capybara/).any?
          print "The capybara dependency has been found!"
        else
          print "SOMETHING WENT WRONG"
        end
      }
  end
```

**Rakefile**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'roll_out/rake_tasks'
require 'roll_out/security'
require 'roll_out/jira'
require 'REDACTED/philter/lint_results'
require 'roll_out/capybara'

load 'REDACTED/tasks/REDACTED.rake'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks almost good except .each missing

i did my test and it works fine.

```
Dir.glob('spec/features/*.rb').each do |f|
        puts 'haha' if File.readlines(f).any?{|line| line.include?('capybara')}
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Or a "Gem", I should say.